# Remove dependency from a production build

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to exclude AWS dependencies which I use for local testing from my server build, as they are quite heavy. How would you approach this with Javascript?

```js
"dependencies": {
  "aws-sdk": "^2.639.0"
}
```

I am using UmiJS, which uses Webpack underneath.

I am coming to from a Java world. In Java to achieve that, one would simply mark this dependency as 'test', so that it wouldn't be added to the main package

Comment: dev dependencies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an entry to the "dependencies" attribute of a package.json file, on the command line, run the following command:

```
npm install <package-name> [--save-prod]
```

To add an entry to the "devDependencies" attribute of a package.json file, on the command line, run the following command:

```
npm install <package-name> --save-dev
```